# Is Google Cloud Platform a broker?

Tags: mqtt, microsoft-windows-iot

I am trying to develop an windows form application on Visual Studio to control a home automation system. I am looking into the MQTT protocol to communicate between an application AMD hardware (using the ESP32). My lecturer told me to subscribe to the Google Cloud Platform, which I have. But I don't really understand MQTT fully at the moment and have a couple of questions. Mainly:

- Is the Google Cloud Platform a broker which I can subscribe and publish to with the application and esp32?
- Is it possible to do this through Visual Studio?

Any information provided would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.